# How do you design SQL database in Azure without diagrams?

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure

I had to move some of my databases from SQL Server hosted in my pc to Azure.
In order to import my DBs Azure demanded that I remove diagrams.

And in SQLServer explorer in VS2015 there's no possibility to create diagrams.
Diagrams helped me a lot! When you have 10+ tables in DB you could create more then one diagram, which reflects some part of subject area. And all changes in diagram reflected on DB itself, so consistency was maintained (I doubt it would, if I use third party tool for design/diagrams).

So... What's the common approach to database design, if using Azure?
Rely on third party tools? Keep everything in mind (impossible)?

Or, perhaps, I missed something, and diagrams are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure SQL Database doesn't support Database Diagrams as of yet. You have to rely on third party like [dbForge Studio](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/studio/database-diagram.html) for generating these diagrams.

Another approach is to create a simple console application in C# and generate EDMX using Entity Framework, this would still suffice for graphical user interface.

Also you can use [SQL Database Migration tool](https://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/), which can get your Azure SQL Database to your local SQL Server and can generate schema diagrams.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe This could help? https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2013/10/26/create-database-diagrams-of-your-windows-azure-sql-databases/ It's a blog post by a friend of mine talking about just that... Hope it helps ... BTW did You install SSTD on VS? If nog that might already help too

Answer (score 1):

You can now do this in the preview version of 2016 SSMS.  google "SQL Server Management Studio preview" or try https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx